# Error Code 6003 Is Always Reported for the Push Service

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I use huawei mate 30pro for push kit test, but i always get error code 6003.How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the configuration information such as the certificate signature of the application.

The SHA256 fingerprint may not be configured or incorrectly configured on the AGC.

Check whether the debug version and release version use different signature certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the troubleshooting guide [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/faq-0000001050042183-V5).

> What does result code 6003 mean?

> Inconsistent certificate fingerprint configurations.
>
> 1. Ensure that the certificate fingerprint packed in the app on your device is consistent with that configured through SHA-256 certificate fingerprint in AppGallery Connect. For details, please refer to [Getting Started](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-config-agc-0000001050170137-V5).
> 2. HMS Core (APK) will cache the signature file. You need to find HMS Core (APK) on the Apps page of your device and clear its cache, restart your app, and perform the previous operation again.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache was insufficient for me -- I had to delete all of the data for the HMS Core app before it was able to work.